# PHP SIMPLE DOM - div class

Tags: php

please can me help?

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.csfd.cz/hledat/?q=Rychle+a+zb%C4%9Bsile+2001');
```

This code:

```
<div id="search-films" class="ct-general th-1">
    <h2 class="header">Filmy</h2>
    <div class="content">

        <ul class="ui-image-list js-odd-even">
            <li>
                <a href="/film/1616-rychle-a-zbesile/"><img src="//img.csfd.cz/files/images/film/posters/000/001/1619_405078.jpg?h180" alt="poster" class="film-poster-small image" /></a>
                <div>
                    <h3 class="subject"><a href="/film/1616-rychle-a-zbesile/" class="film c1">Rychle a zběsile</a></h3>



                    <p>Akční / Krimi, USA / Německo, 2001</p>
                    <p>
                        Režie: <a href="/tvurce/2850-rob-cohen/">Rob Cohen</a><br>
                        Hrají: <a href="/tvurce/2218-paul-walker/">Paul Walker</a>, <a href="/tvurce/129-vin-diesel/">Vin Diesel</a><br>
                    </p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

How to only this: img.csfd.cz/files/images/film/posters/000/001/1619_405078.jpg?h180 and this /film/1616-rychle-a-zbesile/ ...? Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you want get value of src using simple_html_dom than you can try following code:

1) From html content:-

```
include("simple_html_dom.php"); // Download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/
$html = new simple_html_dom();   
$html->load(YOUR_HTML_CONTENT); 
foreach($html->find('img') as $a)
    echo $a->src;
```

2) From URL:-

```
include("simple_html_dom.php"); 
$html = file_get_html(YOUR_URL); 
foreach($html->find('img') as $a) 
   echo $a->src . '<br>';
```

Comment: '<?php   
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';


$html = file_get_html('http://www.csfd.cz/hledat/?q=Rychle+a+zb%C4%9Bsile+2001');   
$html = new simple_html_dom();   
$html->load(YOUR_HTML_CONTENT); 
foreach($html->find('img') as $a)
    echo $a->src;'

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT' in D:\wamp64\www\csfd\simple_html_dom.php on line 76
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 239128 {main}( ) ...\index.php:0
2 0.0064 754400 file_get_html( ) ...\index.php:7
3 0.0065 759856 get_curl( ) ...\simple_html_dom.php:100

( ! ) Notice: Use of undefined constant ROOT - assumed 'ROOT' in D:\wamp64\www\csfd\simple_html_dom.php on line 77
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0005 239128 {main}( ) ...\index.php:0
2 0.0064 754400 file_get_html( ) ...\index.php:7

Comment: include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('http://www.csfd.cz/hledat/?q=Rychle+a+zb%C4%9%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BBsile+2001'); 
foreach($html->find('img') as $a)
    echo $a->src . '<br>';

Comment: you included simple_html_dom.php file, right? if not than Download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/